# maven-javadoc-plugin error javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1 with non-ASCII characters in directory name

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm using OpenJDK 11 on Windows 10. I have a very simple POM, for a single Java file, that generates Javadocs. Here is an extract:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Strangely just running `mvn clean package` causes an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.1:jar (default) on project foobar: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: C:\bin\jdk-11\bin\javadoc.exe @options @packages
```

In `target/apidocs` there are only three files: `javadoc.bat`, `options`, and `packages`. The `options` file is the most interesting. It explicitly says `UTF-8` everywhere, as it should. But look at these lines:

```
-sourcepath
C:/projects/li��o 1/src/main/java
```

This project is in `C:\projects\lição 1`. It appears that somewhere along the chain Java or Maven or the Javadoc plugin didn't correctly convert the directory name to UTF-8.

Sure enough; when I renamed the directories in Windows to remove non-ASCII characters, `mvn clean package` worked just fine.

This would seem like a blatant bug; once Maven starts, everything should be UTF-8 throughout. Is it a problem with the Javadoc plugin? Anyone have an idea where this originates? Where should I file a bug ticket? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First you have defined the source encoding ...the question is which encoding is given to the JVM which is used by Maven? https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MJAVADOC/ ?

Comment: Have you tried to add `<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>` to `<properties>` block?

Comment: Can you provide me some reference to what this is supposed to do, or is this a guess of something you haven't tried?

Comment: Note that https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html is clear that `encoding` defaults to `project.build.sourceEncoding`. But we're talking about the interpretation of directory names. I think this is a bug.

Comment: Mikhail, `docencoding` (which is the configuration that uses the `project.reporting.outputEncoding` you referred to) specifies to the _output_ encoding. How would this have anything to do with the encoding of the directory names the plugin places in the `options` file? Have you actually reproduced this on your machine? Have you actually seen this `options` file I'm talking about? Do you understand the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, this looks like the encoding used to write the files to `target/apidocs`.

Looking through the source for the maven-javadoc-plugin, it is just using the platform encoding when writing these files - e.g. [this line](https://github.com/apache/maven-javadoc-plugin/blob/3dcf135299950db9541f7da671bec1a84c5cef49/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/javadoc/AbstractJavadocMojo.java#L4373).

Directly setting the encoding while calling Maven repaired the example above for me:

```
mvn clean package -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

This feels more like a workaround than a good fix though - it needs to assume there is nothing else depending on the platform encoding in the Maven build.

I think the cause is a change in the main JDK between 8 and 9.  The bit of code (actually under javac) that parses the argument files (e.g. `@options` in the javadoc command line) has switched from using the platform encoding [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/1ff9d5118aae/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/main/CommandLine.java#l74) to calling `Files.newBufferedReader()` [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/langtools/file/65bfdabaab9c/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/main/CommandLine.java#l127).  [Files.newBufferedReader(Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path)) states that it uses UTF-8 if the encoding is not specified.  This means argument files, in both javac and javadoc, must now be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: It would seem to me this is indeed a bug. Any idea where we can file bugs for the Maven Javadoc Plugin?

Comment: There's details about their issue tracker in Jira [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/issue-tracking.html).  Can't spot anything obvious already there.

Comment: OK, I've filed [MJAVADOC-581](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-581).

Answer (score 0):

This maven build error was caused by adding some illegal argument in the plugin definition.  For example, I used a  "filter" element and it turned out that the Spring Boot version I was using did not recognize this argument resulting in an obscure "Length=1" error as you posted in the headline.  By removing the illegal argument and problem was cleared.